# Nginx - URL with www dont redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I have nginx installation which is working as proxy for a site. Please see config below

```html
proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=10m  max_size=1g;
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://domainserver.com:8000;
                proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                proxy_send_timeout          600;
                proxy_read_timeout          600;
                send_timeout                600;
        }
        location = /xmlrpc.php {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }
        location = /home-garden {
                rewrite 301 http://domain.com/category/forsale/home-and-garden/;
        }

}
```

What I want to do is

URL
http://www.domain.com/home-garden should redirect to http://domain.com/new-home-garden

Also,
http://domain.com/home-garden should redirect to http://domain.com/new-home-garden

Let me know if I gave enough information and if someone can help me

Comment: What is `rewrite 301 http://domain.com/category/forsale/home-and-garden/;`? Do you mean `return`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a new server block to catch `www.domain.com` and then redirect to `domain.com`. This is the first server block below. Note that this will redirect **all** requests from `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`. If this is not the intention, it can be customised.

Then, you'll need to remove `www.domain.com` from the `server_name` directive in the second server block.

For the redirect, define a new location block as shown below.

```html
proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=10m  max_size=1g;

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.com;

        return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://domainserver.com:8000;
                proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                proxy_send_timeout          600;
                proxy_read_timeout          600;
                send_timeout                600;
        }
        location = /xmlrpc.php {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }
        location ^~ /home-garden {
                rewrite 301 http://domain.com/new-home-garden/;
        }

}
```

Comment: This worked ..... but location ^~ /home-garden {
                rewrite 301 http://domain.com/new-home-garden/;
        } didnt worked after it was redirected from www.domain.com so i used proxy as of now... but I dont know if its a correct way

Comment: I see... Proxying isn't the same as redirecting, though. When you say the redirect didn't work after it was redirected from `www.domain.com`, does that mean that `domain.com/home-garden` did redirect properly?

Comment: I mean it got redirected from www.domain.com to domain.com ... but didnt go to http://domain.com/new-home-garden